# why wordpress keeps redirecting to old page after deleting it?

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I have a WordPress theme which contains multiple pages one is a contact page, I didn't like this contact page so created another page so the old page I renamed it to `https://videommerce.com/contactold/` and the new one I named it  `https://videommerce.com/contact/` now I deleted the old page page `https://videommerce.com/contactold/`

The problem:

Now when I visit `https://videommerce.com/contact/` it redirects me to `https://videommerce.com/contactold/`

What do I need to do solve this problem?

Comment: Appears to work fine.

Comment: Because redirect will be cached sometimes, you may try using other browsers to see if the same thing happen. If not, it should probably be the cache. After expiration, the problem will be gone or you could clear cache if you don't have to keep those cache files (after you confirm if it is the cache problem)